# Updating input using react state and vice versa

Tags: reactjs, state

I am using an input field, and initially i update it using state.

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.opp.description} />
```

But when i run this. The input does not change value at all.

**My motive is to initially update input using state and then update the state using input value.**

I tried using onChange but that also is not working.

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.opp.description} onChange={this.handleChange} />

var handleChange=(e)=>{
  this.setState({opp:{description:e.target.value}});
}
```

Please suggest how should I do this.

Comment: can you post the code to your whole class so we can see what you have done wrong? just saying its not working doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state won't change unless for each change on the input, you set the state to the latest value on the input.

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.opp.description} onChange={this.onInputChange} />
---------------------------------------------------------
onInputChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    opp: {
      description: e.target.value
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

working example -> https://codesandbox.io/embed/vnjmyzp535

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha if this doesn't work you're doing something really wrong. Take a look at my working example 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vnjmyzp535

Comment: worked. I was putting handleChange inside render. Maybe thats why it wasnt working

Comment: putting methods, or anything other than the JSX you're returning shouldn't be on the render() function.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onChange` handler to your input, then you can update your state whenever the input changes.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({opp: { description: e.target.value } })
}

<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.opp.description} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    opp: {
      description: ''
    }
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      opp: { description: e.target.value }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.opp.description}
        />
      state: {this.state.opp.description}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```